# Classification of abelian groups of order 72, and subgroups of order 4

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

> **Problem** :
>
> 1. Find all abelian groups of order 72, up to isomorphism.
> 2. Which one of those groups are cyclic?
> 3. Amont these subgroups, find all groups with a unique subgroup of order 4.

**My answer** : Let $G$ a abelian group such that $|G|=72=2^33^2$. We can find the elementary divisors of $G$ : $(2^3,3^2) ; (2,2^2,3^2) ; (2,2,2,3^2) ; (2^3,3,3);(2,2^2,3,3);(2,2,2,3,3)$.

It follows that $G$ is isomorphic to 6 abelian groups of order 72: $$C_{72}$$ $$C_2\times C_{36},C_2\times C_2\times C_2$$ $$C_{24}\times C_3, C_6\times C_{12}, C_2\times C_6\times C_6$$

Now I can't seem to find which groups are cyclic. Quite intuitively I would say $C_{72}$ is cyclic because generated by $1$, $C_2\times C_{36},C_2\times C_2\times C_2$ is generated by $(1,1,1)$ but I don't have a rigorous answer.

For the subgroup of order 4, I know that if $G$ is a cyclic group of order $m$ and if $n|m$, then there exists a unique subgroup of $G$ of order $n$. Then the group $C_{72}$ has a unique subgroup of order $4$ but what about the others?

Comment: The *only* cyclic group is the first one, of course: $\;C_{72}\;$ , since there is only one cyclic group, up to isomorphism, for any order ( up to $\;\aleph_0\,$). And this is a rigurous argument which, I presume, is studied way before classifying finite abelian groups up to isomorphism.